# How to find External IP in html/js

Tags: javascript, html, ip

I am hosting a website on github (a static server), and I made a form that collects emails for the newsletter.
I thought I had figured out how to do it, but I was getting internal ips, not external.

---

I have looked though a lot of other posts, but none seem to work with "Value" in forms.

```js
var findIP = new Promise(r=>{var w=window,a=new (w.RTCPeerConnection||w.mozRTCPeerConnection||w.webkitRTCPeerConnection)({iceServers:[]}),b=()=>{};a.createDataChannel("");a.createOffer(c=>a.setLocalDescription(c,b,b),b);a.onicecandidate=c=>{try{c.candidate.candidate.match(/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g).forEach(r)}catch(e){}}})

findIP.then(ip => document.getElementById('saveIP').value = ip).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

```html
<form>
<input id=saveIP name="IP" value="replace">
</form>
  <!-- normally hidden -->
```

Does anyone know how to update this JS to give me the external ip?
Thanks in advance, -fred

Comment: do you want to collect the public ip??

Comment: yes @tuhin47 , so I see where people are from.